# How to populate list in Flutter while fetching data from api

Tags: http, flutter

I wish to make a list of available services in a city from selected state and category. That would require passing 3 parameters namely, State, City and Category. I am taking data from this API https://api.covid19india.org/resources/resources.json . Please tell me how can I make a ListView for same.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should provide which code you have tried so far, your expected output, a way for us to reproduce it... I encourage you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Hi @Shaashank check my code on github about the API call and setting on the list as follow https://github.com/ravindra0821/Corno-Flutter-App

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at the official `ListView` documentation. The concept is pretty easy.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html